# how can make the content of code to be displayed in the wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to php and web ,wrote lines of code in my wprdpress wiht `pre` tag ,when i published it ,many code lines can not be watched ,how can i set my wordpress properly?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default you can't use php inside posts/pages. There are plugins that will allow you to use php inside posts/pages though. [This](https://wordpress.org/plugins/allow-php-in-posts-and-pages/) is on of them. Once installed and activated, edit the post/page and type in your php code, but you use `[php]` and `[/php]` instead of `<?php` and `?>`

e.g.

```
[php]
echo "Hello world!";
[/php]
```

will print out

```
Hello world!
```

on your page.

Comment: That method make my wordpress crashed.

Comment: Hmm that odd. There are other plugins that allow you to use php, try one of them? (simply searching for `php` will return a good few results.

Comment: i don't know why ,prolem solved when i reinstall my wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong way to do it (unsecure and not stable).

You can use differents ways, shortcode or template page.

Shortcode => http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API
You use tags in your text editor like

```
[myshortcode]
```

and you specify for example in your functions.php file in your theme :

```
function myshortcode_func( $atts ){
//do your PHP stuff
return "your data to display";
}
add_shortcode( 'myshortcode', 'myshortcode_func' );
```

Another way is to create a new template file in your theme,
Example : create a file template.php file
In your file specify template name :

```
/*
Template Name:Mytemplate
*/
//your php stuff
```

And then go to your wordpress admin, create a page, and choose in template select your template name.

Then if you go on the page your php will be executed.

It's fast explanation, i recommend you to learn how to you both of these ways.